# Leveling select fields

Tags: json, jq

I am fetching a json response of following structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "abcdef",
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_1.jpg"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "title": "Boring Title One"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "ghijkl",
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_2.jpg"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "title": "Boring Title Two"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "mnopqr",
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_3.jpg"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "title": "Boring Title Three"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "stuvwx",
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_4.jpg"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "title": "Boring Title Four"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to have a shortened json like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "abcdef",
            "title": "Boring Title One",
            "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "ghijkl",
            "title": "Boring Title Two",
            "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "mnopqr",
            "title": "Boring Title Three",
            "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "stuvwx",
            "title": "Boring Title Four",
            "url": "https://example.com/somefiles_4.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

If this is not possible I can work with joining those three values into a single string and latter split when necessary; like this:

```
abcdef@Boring Title One@https://example.com/somefiles_1.jpg
ghijkl@Boring Title Two@https://example.com/somefiles_2.jpg
mnopqr@Boring Title Three@https://example.com/somefiles_3.jpg
stuvwx@Boring Title Four@https://example.com/somefiles_4.jpg
```

This is where I am. I was uring the `jq` with `select()` and then pipe the results to `to_entries` like this:

```
jq -r '.data.children[] | select(.data.post_type|test("image")?) | .data | to_entries[] | [ .value.title , .value.preview.images[0].source.url ] | join("@")' ~/Documents/json/sample.json
```

1. I don't understand what goes after `to_entries[]`; I have tried multiple variations of .key and .values; Mostly I don't get any result but sometimes I get key pairs I do not intend to select. How to learn the proper syntax for it?
2. Is creating a flat json out of a nested json like this good or is it better to create the string outputs? I feel the string might be error prone especially with the presence of spaces or special characters.

Comment: There is no post_type field in your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what you're looking for is the `{field}` syntax. You don't need to resort to *string outputs*.

```
{ data: [
    .data.children[].data
    | select(has("post_type") and (.post_type | index("image")))
    | {id, title} + (.preview.images[].source | {url})
  # or, if images array always contains one element:
  # | {id, title, url: .preview.images[0].source.url}
  ]
}
```

Comment: this works including the filtering by post_type. I expected creating new json to be complex so was looking to making a string.

Comment: not sure if I should ask this as a new question or not.... can the `select(has(key))` used in adding a value if a key exists and if not add the value from another pair? Like if `video_url` exists add it to `url` key else add `image_url` value to `url` key? I realize this strays far from the question and above example

Comment: @Bahrath yes, I think you should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to the main question is:

```
{data: [.data.children[]
        | .data
        | {id, title, url: .preview.images[0].source.url} ]}
```

(The "post_type" seems to have disappeared, but hopefully if it's relevant, you will be able to adapt the above as required.  Likewise if `.images[1]` and beyond are relevant.)

### String Output

If you want linear output, you should probably consider CSV or TSV, both of which are supported by jq via `@csv` and `@tsv` respectively.

Comment: the url part is interesting. It would help me add more key-values nested at various places. this with oguz's answer works how I wanted.